# Sumar dos columnas en formato de fecha y mostrar solo la hora con python usando pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sum

Buen Día

Tengo el siguiente problema con un dataframe en donde dos de sus columnas con formato de fecha las debo de sumar solo las horas ya que las dos columnas las cambie a formato de tiempo para poder realizar la suma

```
df['STARTTIME']= pd.to_datetime(df['STARTTIME'])

df['DURATION']= pd.to_datetime(df['DURATION'],format= '%H:%M:%S')
```

[image: Starttime y duración]

me podrían recomendar alguna solución para saber el total de solo las horas

Comment: Y que problemas tienes al hacerlo? Acaso no te basta con hacer `df['STARTTIME'] + df['DURATION']`?

Comment: `df['DURATION']= pd.to_timedelta(df["DURATION"])` ?

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo pero si lo intente, pero al parecer estoy omitiendo ¡algo!.                          me genera el siguiente error:     no se puede agregar datetimearray                                                             
  TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray

Comment: df['STARTTIME']= df['STARTTIME'].str.extract('(..:..:..)',expand= True)
df['STARTTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['STARTTIME'],format= '%H:%M:%S')
df['DURATION']= pd.to_datetime(df['DURATION'],format= '%H:%M:%S')                                                                   
df['END']=  df['STARTTIME']- df['DURATION']                                                        puedo realizar la diferencia pero la suma no

Comment: Operaciones soportadas:

Operación

Resultado

datetime2 = datetime1 + timedelta

(1)

datetime2 = datetime1 - timedelta

(2)

timedelta = datetime1 - datetime2

(3)

datetime1 < datetime2

Compara datetime to datetime.  y es la causa de mi problema gracias compañeros

Comment: Buen día, toda la información que agregaste en los comentarios debería ir en la pregunta (En la parte inferior hay un botón para editar), te recomiendo leer la sección [ask] y hacer el [tour]. Por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen y el código con el que podamos reproducir tu problema.